# jupyter lab notebook gets frozen with matplotlib widget cursor

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I would like to fill a `ipywidgets.widgets.Output()` with a `matplotlib imshow` and a `matplotlib.widgets.Cursor` for further processing when the user clicks on the point showed by the cursor. Here is the code that I run in my jupyter notebook.

```
%matplotlib ipympl

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as mpl_widgets
from ipywidgets import widgets

out = widgets.Output()

with out:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,200)),aspect="auto")
    cursor = mpl_widgets.Cursor(ax,useblit=True)
    plt.show()
out
```

When my notebook is played, `Jupyter` is immediately and always busy sending many stuffs on the network (e.g. favicon, favicon_busy ...) even when I am not interacting with my widget and ending up by, first, lagging more and more when moving the cursor and, ultimately, by getting frozen after several thousands of requests. Removing the cursor reduces drastically the number of requests. Would you have any idea of what is wrong with my code ?

Here is my setup:

- Browsers: Firefox and Chrome
- Python: 3.5.2
- MatPlotLib: 3.0.2
- JupyterLab v0.35.4
- Jupyter extensions:

  - @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v0.38.1
  - jupyter-matplotlib v0.3.0